# How to pass the variable of .aspx.cs to .aspx?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="PlayerInfo_DataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PlayerInfo_ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [player_info]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [player_info] SET
        [account_id] = @account_id,
        [player_level] = @player_level,
        [player_exp] = @player_exp        
        WHERE [player_uid] = @player_uid">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to pass the variable of .aspx.cs to @player_uid.

What shoud I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic approach is by producing some JavaScript code on server such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
        var id = document.getElementById('anElementInpage');
        id.value=<%=theValueIWantToPass %>;
    }
</script>
```

And for passing values from your asp.net page to the parameters have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

@player_uid is a parameter in the query and it does not reside in .aspx.

But if you want to pass a value from cs to aspx one way is through generating java script variables.

Comment: plz coach me the solution. how to use javascript variables?